c multi-dimensional arrays vs pointers
I've struggling to understand some details of how it's possible to access multi-dimensional arrays using pointer arithmetic and have come up with some results that don't seem to make sense:
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    // your code goes here
    
    char a[3][4] = {{1, 2, 3, 4}, {5, 6, 7, 8}, {9, 10, 11, 12}};
    
    printf("*(*(a + 1) + 2) :%d\n", *(*(a + 1) + 2));
    
    printf("size of a:%d, size of *a:%d, size of **a:%d\n",
        sizeof(a), sizeof(*a), sizeof(**a));

    printf("value of a:%d, value of *a:%d, value of **a:%d\n",
        a, *a, **a);
    
    
    return 0;
}

prints
*(*(a + 1) + 2) :7
*(a + 1) :593886528
a + 1 :593886528
size of a:12, size of *a:4, size of **a:1
value of a:593886524, value of *a:593886524, value of **a:1

I don't see what's going on under the hood so that printing a gives you the address of the first element of a, dereferencing it once gives the same value again rather than the contents, but, magically, deferencing a second time gets the value actually pointed to. How does this "pointer to itself that knows when to actually dereference (all while keepiung track of the correct size)" work?

Does this answer your question? 2D array vs array of arrays

You should print pointers with %p. The compiler ought to emit a warning about that.

*a does give you the contents of a.  The contents of a is an array, and the array decays to a pointer to its first element when you pass it to a function.  So you are passing the address to printf.  That address happens to be the same as the address of the first element of a, but the object it points to has a different size.

You should also know that *(a + 1) is exactly the same as a[1] so pointer arithmetic is not a part of this.

The %d printf conversion format specifier is for int. However, using the sizeof operator yields a value of type size_t. The correct specifier for size_t is %zu. See the documentation for printf for further information. By using the wrong specifier, you are invoking undefined behavior.

And a corollary to @AndreasWenzel' s point: printing pointers requires the %p format specifier and casting the pointer to (void *) in the call to printf().  That produces a system-specific result.  You can control the format if you use <stdint.h> and a format such as 0x%.12" PRIXPTR and casting the pointer to (uintptr_t) in the call to printf().

An array, when used in an expression, decays to a pointer to its first element.  This applies to an array of arrays as well.
The address of an array will be the same as the address of its first element (although the types will be different).  And since you have an array of arrays, the address of the outer array is the same as that of the first inner array, which is the same as that of the first element of the inner array.
Looking at this from the perspective of types, when you print a you get a pointer to its first element.  Since the type of a is char[3][4], that means the elements of the array are of type char[4] and a pointer to those elements has type char(*)[4].
When you then print *a, this expression has type char[4] which also decays to a pointer to its first element of type char *.
So a and *a both denote arrays, and both decay to a pointer to their first element.
On a side node, you should use the %p format specifier when printing pointers.  The %d specifier is for printing an int, and using the wrong format specifier triggers undefined behavior in your code.

Given the declaration
char a[3][4];

all of the following are true:
 Expression      Type           Decays to      Evaluates to
 ----------      ----           ---------      ------------
         &a      char (*)[3][4] n/a            Address of the entire array object         
          a      char [3][4]    char (*)[4]    Address of first element (which itself is an array)
        a+i      char (*)[4]    n/a            Address of the i'th element (which is itself an array)
         *a      char [4]       char *         Address of first element of first subarray; equivalent to a[0]
     *(a+i)      char [4]       char *         Address of the first element of the i'th subarray; equivalent to a[i]
       a[i]      char [4]       char *         Address of first element of i'th subarray
      *a[i]      char           n/a            Value of the first element of the j'th subarray; equivalent to a[i][0]
     a[i]+j      char *         n/a            Address of the j'th element of the i'th subarray
*(*(a+i)+j)      char           n/a            Value of the j'th element of the i'th subarray
    a[i][j]      char           n/a            Value of the j'th element of the i'th subarray

Graphically (addresses are for illustration only):
Address       char            char *          char (*)[4]
------- +---+ ----            ------          -----------
0x1000  | 1 | a[0][0],*a[0]   *a+0,a[0]       &a,a,a+0
        + - + 
0x1001  | 2 | a[0][1]         *a+1
        + - +
0x1002  | 3 | a[0][2]         *a+2 
        + - +
0x1003  | 4 | a[0][3]         *a+3
        +---+
0x1004  | 5 | a[1][0],*a[1]   *(a+1)+0,a[1]  a+1
        + - + 
0x1005  | 6 | a[1][1]         *(a+1)+1    
        + - +
0x1006  | 7 | a[1][2]         *(a+1)+2
        + - +
0x1007  | 8 | a[1][3]         *(a+1)+3
        +---+
0x1008  | 9 | a[2][0],*a[2]   *(a+2)+0,a[2]  a+2
        + - +  
0x1009  | a | a[2][1]         *(a+2)+1
        + - +
0x100a  | b | a[2][2]         *(a+2)+2
        + - + 
0x100b  | c | a[2][3]         *(a+2)+3
        +---+

What's clear from this is that the expressions &a, a, &a[0], a[0], and &a[0][0] will all yield the same address value (0x1000), but the types of the expressions are different (char (*)[3][4], char (*)[4], char (*)[4], char *, and char *).
a[i]     == *(a + i)
a[i][j]  == *(a[i] + j) == *(*(a + i) + j)

Couple of notes:

to print pointer values, use %p and cast the argument to (void *): printf("value of a: %p\n", (void *) a);
to print results from sizeof, use %zu: printf("sizeof a: %zu\n", sizeof a);

Note that sizeof is an operator like * and ++, not a function; parentheses are only needed if the operand is a type name or you need the size of an arithmetic expression like sizeof (a+b).

Under the hood  memory is just a linear sequence of bytes. C has no multidimensional arrays, like FORTRAN: There is just array. But an array can be an array of an array, an array on an array of an array, and so on. This way there is a multi-dimensional view.
The other thing to consider is that in C an array is stored by line in memory.
I will use your program (with a few changes), and a memory dump of it in execution. This way we have some examples. a in the example below is declared int a[3][4] so we can see pointer arithmetic in action, since the sizes of char and int are different (in the original code a is char[][]). Code is at the end.
Consider
    int a[3][4] = {
        { 1,  2,  3,  4},
        { 5,  6,  7,  8},
        { 9, 10, 11, 12}
    };

if the address of a is 0x55FC1C (using 32-bit model) in memory we see
0x0055FC14  cc cc cc cc 11 11 11 11 01 00 00 00 02 00 00 00  ÌÌÌÌ............
0x0055FC24  03 00 00 00 04 00 00 00 05 00 00 00 06 00 00 00  ................
0x0055FC34  07 00 00 00 08 00 00 00 09 00 00 00 0a 00 00 00  ................
0x0055FC44  0b 00 00 00 0c 00 00 00 22 22 22 22 33 33 33 33  ........""""3333

It is running in a little-endian machine with 4-byte int so the first byte is the least significant, and this is why we see 1 as 01 00 00 00. And we see that data is laid in memory by line.
As your compiler or IDE can show you:

a is int[3][4], a 12-int array
so a[0] is int[4], as are also a[1] and a[2]
a[0][0] is int, as every element of a. This is the meaning of the declaration, anyway: an array of 12 int.

Arrays in C are base plus an offset.
The example
#include < stdio.h>

typedef struct
{
    int pre_a;
    int a[3][4];
    int pos_a;
    int other;
} Container;

int main(void)
{
#pragma pack(show)
#pragma pack(push, 1)
#pragma pack(show)
    // clang-format-off
    int pre_a   = 0x11111111;
    int a[3][4] = {
        {1, 2, 3, 4}, {5, 6, 7, 8}, {9, 10, 11, 12}};
    int pos_a = 0x22222222;
    int other = 0x33333333;
    // same values inside struct
    Container cont = {
        .pre_a = 0x11111111,
        .a = {{1, 2, 3, 4}, {5, 6, 7, 8}, {9, 10, 11, 12}},
        .pos_a = 0x22222222,
        .other = 0x33333333};
    // clang-format-on
#pragma pack(pop)
#pragma pack(show)

    printf(
        "\n\
(32 bits memory model)\n\
int pre_a   at\t0x%p\n\
int a[3][4] at\t0x%p\n\
int pos_a   at\t0x%p\n\
\n\
container   at\t0x%p\n",
        &pre_a, &a, &pos_a, &cont);

    printf(
        "(address of a[2][3]) - (address of a[0][0]) = "
        "%d\n\n",
        (&a[2][3] - &a[0][0]));
    printf(
        "(address of a[0][1]) - (address of a[0][0]) = "
        "%d (as int*)\n",
        (&a[0][1] - &a[0][0]));

    char* pa = (char*) &a[0][0];
    char* pb = (char*) &a[0][1];

    printf(
        "(address of a[0][1]) - (address of a[0][0]) = %d (as char*)\n",
        (pb - pa));
    printf(
        "\n\
    size of a:\t%2d (a is int[3][4]),\n\
           *a:\t%2d (*a is int[4])\n\
          **a:\t%2d (**a) is int\n",
        sizeof(a), sizeof(*a), sizeof(**a));

    int(*p_array_4i_a)[4] = (int(*)[4])&a[2];
    printf(
        "\n\tint[4] array pointed to a[2]: %d,%d,%d,%d\n",
        (*p_array_4i_a)[0], (*p_array_4i_a)[1],
        (*p_array_4i_a)[2], (*p_array_4i_a)[3]);

    return 0;
}

The output
(32 bits memory model)
int pre_a   at  0x0055FCAC
int a[3][4] at  0x0055FC74
int pos_a   at  0x0055FC68

container   at  0x0055FC18
(address of a[2][3]) - (address of a[0][0]) = 11

(address of a[0][1]) - (address of a[0][0]) = 1 (as int*)
(address of a[0][1]) - (address of a[0][0]) = 4 (as char*)

    size of a:  48 (a is int[3][4]),
           *a:  16 (*a is int[4])
          **a:   4 (**a) is int

        int[4] array pointed to a[2]: 9,10,11,12

Notes on the example

Since a[i] is int[4] we can declare a pointer to such a thing and, as a test, copy a[2] to it and print it by declaring

    int(*p_array_4i_a)[4] = (int(*)[4])&a[2];
    printf(
        "\n\tint[4] array pointed to a[2]: %d,%d,%d,%d\n",
        (*p_array_4i_a)[0], (*p_array_4i_a)[1],
        (*p_array_4i_a)[2], (*p_array_4i_a)[3]);

and see
        int[4] array pointed to a[2]: 9,10,11,12


packing: see that in memory variables can be allocated at inverted order, and extra bytes can be inserted for alignment:

typedef struct
{
    int pre_a;
    int a[3][4];
    int pos_a;
    int other;
} Container;

#pragma pack(show)
#pragma pack(push, 1)
#pragma pack(show)
   int pre_a   = 0x11111111;
    int a[3][4] = {
        {1, 2, 3, 4},
        {5, 6, 7, 8},
        {9, 10, 11, 12}
    };
    int pos_a = 0x22222222;
    int other = 0x33333333;
    // same values inside struct
    Container cont = {
        .pre_a = 0x11111111,
        .a = {
            {1, 2, 3, 4},
            {5, 6, 7, 8},
            {9, 10, 11, 12}
        },
        .pos_a = 0x22222222,
        .other = 0x33333333};
#pragma pack(pop)
#pragma pack(show)

The Container struct has the same variables, initialized in cont with the same values, so we can see the differences im memory at run time. The addresses are printed, so we can stop the program at the end an take a loop at them.
These #pragma pack things are instructions to the compiler --- MSVC here, but others are similar --- to use 1-byte alignment in this segment and then restore it to the previous setting --- 8 is the standard in MSVC in this machine.
See the memory layout for the 2 versions of the same data:
0x0055FBF4  94 fc 55 00 cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc 78 fc 55 00  ”üU.ÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌxüU.
0x0055FC04  cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc 74 fc 55 00 cc cc cc cc  ÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌtüU.ÌÌÌÌ
0x0055FC14  cc cc cc cc 11 11 11 11 01 00 00 00 02 00 00 00  ÌÌÌÌ............
0x0055FC24  03 00 00 00 04 00 00 00 05 00 00 00 06 00 00 00  ................
0x0055FC34  07 00 00 00 08 00 00 00 09 00 00 00 0a 00 00 00  ................
0x0055FC44  0b 00 00 00 0c 00 00 00 22 22 22 22 33 33 33 33  ........""""3333
0x0055FC54  cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc 33 33 33 33 cc cc cc cc  ÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌ3333ÌÌÌÌ
0x0055FC64  cc cc cc cc 22 22 22 22 cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc  ÌÌÌÌ""""ÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌ
0x0055FC74  01 00 00 00 02 00 00 00 03 00 00 00 04 00 00 00  ................
0x0055FC84  05 00 00 00 06 00 00 00 07 00 00 00 08 00 00 00  ................
0x0055FC94  09 00 00 00 0a 00 00 00 0b 00 00 00 0c 00 00 00  ................
0x0055FCA4  cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc 11 11 11 11 cc cc cc cc  ÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌ....ÌÌÌÌ
0x0055FCB4  aa d7 7c 55 d8 fc 55 00 e3 21 bb 00 01 00 00 00  ª×|UØüU.ã!».....

The first group is the Container struct and the data is in the order the struct members are declared and with no aligment. In the second group, the same data shows many alignment bytes with value 0xcc, and the order is inverted. Alignment directives does not work outside the struct.

pointer arithmetic: see this lines

    printf(
       "(address of a[2][3]) - (address of a[0][0]) = "
       "%d\n\n",
       (&a[2][3] - &a[0][0]));
   printf(
       "(address of a[0][1]) - (address of a[0][0]) = "
       "%d (as int*)\n",
       (&a[0][1] - &a[0][0]));

   char* pa = (char*) &a[0][0];
   char* pb = (char*) &a[0][1];

   printf(
       "(address of a[0][1]) - (address of a[0][0]) = %d (as char*)\n",
       (pb - pa));

and the output:
container   at  0x0055FC18
(address of a[2][3]) - (address of a[0][0]) = 11

(address of a[0][1]) - (address of a[0][0]) = 1 (as int*)
(address of a[0][1]) - (address of a[0][0]) = 4 (as char*)

There are 11 int between a[0][0] and a[2][3] and the printf output shows that C knows about int pointers and int size. Copying the pointers to char* ones the compiler now shows the difference between 1s and 2nd elements being 4 and not 1.
